# Multiple Fonts used for Navigation Bar Titles

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Wondering if this is possible...for simplicity's sake lets say I have an app that uses a navigation controller and the app has two sections "News" and "Sports".

I set a custom font in the navigation controller and that effects both the News and Sports titles. Is there a way to override that initial font setting and use a separate font for just the Sports title? So effectively I'd be using one font for the News title and a different one for the Sports title.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Set a title view instead of a title. Now each view controller is in total charge.

Comment: Thanks matt. I'm new at this. I'll check into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with This. Its work in Obj c.

```
 for (UIView *view in self.navigationItem.titleView.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}


UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
self.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = textView;


NSString *newsTitle = @"News Title";
NSString *sportTtle = @"Sport Title";
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", newsTitle,sportTtle];
textView.text = title;
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0];
NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,NSFontAttributeName:font};//
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:textView.attributedText];
[attrStr addAttributes:attrs range:[textView.text rangeOfString:sportTtle]];
textView.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Swift Code:

func customizeNavigationTitle(){

```
    let textView :UITextView = UITextView();
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = textView;

    let newsTitle:NSString = "News Title"
    let sportTtle:NSString = "Sport Title"

    var title =  String(format: "%@%@", newsTitle,sportTtle)
    textView.text = title;
    var color:UIColor = UIColor.redColor();
    var font:UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)!

    //Helvetica Neue


    var attrs:AnyObject = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color ,NSFontAttributeName: font]
    var attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string:title, attributes:attrs as! [String : AnyObject]) as! NSMutableAttributedString;

     var range = textView.text.rangeOfString(sportTtle as String)!

    var attrSports = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color ,NSFontAttributeName: font]

    var textRange = NSRange(location:newsTitle.length , length: sportTtle.length)
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor .greenColor(), range: textRange)
    textView.attributedText = attrStr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your viewDidLoad()

```
titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44))
titleLabel.text = "Discover"
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Light", size: 21)
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center            
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```